# How to find the speed of an object being slowed only by the friction from a curved wall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I created a problem that I am now having trouble finding the solution to.
Imagine a block sliding against a curved wall. The wall forms closed loop. There is friction (some value mu) between the block on the wall. But the block is either on a frictionless table or this is happening somewhere like the ISS where a table would not be needed (like in a block in a tube in freefall). The point being that the only thing slowing the block down is the friction from the curved wall.
You know the initial velocity of the block (V), the radius of the curve (R) and the coefficient (mu). I need a formula that would tell me the velocity at any time (t).

Additional thoughts: I know that the acceleration of friction will be mu * force normal and I believe that force normal will be equal to the centripetal force. If so, that makes it tricky because the acceleration of the friction will depend on the velocity and the velocity at any time will depend on the acceleration of friction.
I feel like if I had an equation for the acceleration at a given time I could take the integral of it to find the change in velocity. But the formulas I come up with do not have time in them.

Additional question: I tried to do some basic modeling of this on a spreadsheet and (if I did it right) it appears to be a case where the acceleration approaches zero and the velocity also approaches zero but neither actually reach zero. It that correct? Would an object in this situation never actually stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radial acceleration is $a_r=-v^2/r$. The tangential acceleration is $a_t = F_{fric}/m = \mu F_n/m = \mu a_r$. Since $a_t = dv/dt$, we have

\begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{\mu v^2}{r}
\end{equation}

Separation of variables gives:

$$-\frac{\mu}{r}\int dt = \int v^{-2}dv$$

then integrating:

$$v=\frac{1}{\frac{\mu}{r}t + \frac{1}{v_0}} = \frac{dx}{dt}$$

($x$ is the distance the block travels.) Integrating again gives

$$x=\frac{r}{\mu}\ln\left(\frac{\mu}{r}t+\frac{1}{v_0}\right)$$

So you are right, the velocity approaches zero but the block never stops.